# Failed app installation, storage full, safe to delete files manually?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, internal-storage, delete, insufficient-memory

I tried to install NetFlix, and during the installation my phone rebooted. After coming back up, the internal storage space was reported as low (and it is, only a few MB left) so I can't attempt a reinstall.

Netflix is not reported as an installed app, and I cannot uninstall it.

I did a bit poking around (with root access), and the failed netflix installation is still lurking there, in the directory:

`/data/data/com.netflix.mediaclient`

stealing **18.1M** of my precious free space.

The question is: **Can I delete these files safely?**

- My device is [GT-S5570](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Mini) running Android 2.2 with root access.
- Please don't suggest uninstalling "some apps" to free space (in order to reinstall and uninstall Netflix). I have moved all but 6 of my apps to an external partition on my SD card using [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD), so the individual apps don't take up much space. I would have to remove *a lot* to release enough space.
- If you wonder why my space has gone so low, it's because my silly device, has only 160 MB of internal space to begin with. I usually try to keep the free internal space at somewhere around 25MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you do anything - make a Nandroid backup using ClockworkMod Recovery or any other recovery tool that you may have.  This is really important as it means that anything you can can be undone if needed.

That said - I believe you can delete these files.  I've not removed files from /data/data/ manually before, but to the best of my knowledge it won't have any bad side effects.  I recommend you try just renaming that folder to something else to start off with and run your phone for a while to see if anything bad happens, if not then you're good to just remove it.

Comment: Well, looks like it was safe to delete the files. Phone still works fine, and I got my space back.